# Appending Int to an Array Matlab

Tags: arrays, api, matlab

I am using an API to get real data times of trains and am trying to get the closest train time to a user entered time and then display that train time, and the next 4 granted the trains are running. I am reading in the information and the code goes through what its supposed to do but when I look at the array its a bunch of [] brackets in 7 cells instead of the calculated numbers. Any suggestions? Code is below with the API

TEST VALUES:
requestStationSelected = 'University%20City' and requestEndStation = 'Roslyn'

```
%this is the API link for the live data from Septa this will get 30
%results and see which time is closer to the user entered time
requestInfoSeptaLive = ['http://www3.septa.org/hackathon/NextToArrive/' requestStationSelected '/' requestEndStation '/30'];

%Again tries to get the information and if there is a failure it will give
%a probable cause and terminate the program
try
    getInfoSeptaLive = urlread(requestInfoSeptaLive);
catch
    if getInfoSeptaLive ~= '[]'
        disp...
            ('Either the arrival/depart stations dont quite match up or theres a server error. Try again.');
        return;
    else
        disp('Unable to fetch the information from Septa, please try again')
        return;
    end
end
%parses the information returned from the Live API
dataReturnedFromLiveAPI = parse_json(getInfoSeptaLive);
dataReturnedFromLiveAPI = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1};

%gets the size of the API in case there are no trains running
sizeOfDataNoTrains = size(dataReturnedFromLiveAPI, 1);
sizeOfData = size(dataReturnedFromLiveAPI, 2);

counter = 0;

for i = 1:sizeOfData
    scanForClosestTime = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,i}.orig_departure_time;

    trainTimeGivenH = sscanf(scanForClosestTime, '%i');
    findColonTrain = strfind(scanForClosestTime, ':');
    trainTimeGivenMStr = scanForClosestTime(findColonTrain+1:4);
    trainTimeGivenM = int32(str2num(trainTimeGivenMStr));
    trainDepartTimeM = (trainTimeGivenH(1,1) * 60) + (trainTimeGivenM);

    differenceBetweenTimes = trainDepartTimeM - userEnteredMins;
    if trainDepartTimeM < userEnteredMins
        differenceBetweenTimes = userEnteredMins - trainDepartTimeM;
    end

    stopAtEndOfData = sizeOfData;
    goodTimeFrame = 60;
    closestTime = cell(1, stopAtEndOfData);
    storeTheDifference = cell(1, stopAtEndOfData);

    if(differenceBetweenTimes < 60)
        if (counter < 5)
            closestTime{i} = scanForClosestTime;
            storeTheDifference{i} = differenceBetweenTimes;
            counter = counter + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you give valid values for `requestStationSelected` and `requestEndStation` so we can see what the problem looks like? A `[]` means an empty cell - typically, if you assign to a{3} without first doing something with a{1} and a{2}, you will get {[],[],value}.  It looks like that's happening where you assign `closestTime{i}` but without being able to run the code I'm guessing.

Comment: requestStationSelected = 'University%20City' and requestEndStation = 'Roslyn'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign your cell arrays inside the `for` loop:

```
for i = 1:sizeOfData
    ...
        closestTime = cell(1, stopAtEndOfData);
        storeTheDifference = cell(1, stopAtEndOfData);
    ...
end
```

This means that you turn both of them into an array of `{[],[],[],[],[]...}` on every iteration of the loop - so unless the last iteration has a valid "closest Time" in it, your cell array will be all empty arrays - and if it does, all but the last element will still be [].

To fix this, move the two lines to *before* the start of the `for` loop.

The second problem seems to be the indexing of the arrays where you store the results. If you only want five results, I am assuming you want to store them in elements 1 - 5 of your array, and not in "just any" locations.  I would change the code to

```
    if (counter < 5)
        counter = counter + 1;
        closestTime{counter} = scanForClosestTime;
        storeTheDifference{counter} = differenceBetweenTimes;
    end
```

But maybe I misinterpreted how you want to handle that?

Unrelated to your question, you might want to take a look at the line

```
trainTimeGivenMStr = scanForClosestTime(findColonTrain+1:4);
```

It is quite possible that this is not what you intended to do - looking at an example of the response, I found the string `"orig_departure_time":"11:57PM"`. I expect that `findColonTrain == 3`, so that the above line becomes

```
trainTimeGivenMStr = scanForClosestTime(4:4);
```

- just a single character. Perhaps you meant

  trainTimeGivenMStr = scanForClosestTime(findColonTrain+(1:4));

which would turn into

```
trainTimeGivenMStr = scanForClosestTime(4:7);
```

so that

```
trainTimeGivenMStr = '57PM';
```

I hope these three things help you get it all working!

EDIT: had a chance to run your code this morning - discovered a number of other problems. I include below an annotated "working" code: the biggest problem was most likely that you were not handling AM/PM in your code. Note that I used a different json parser - this changed a couple of lines very slightly. I'm sure you can put it back together to work the way you want. This returned valid data in all cells.

```
dataReturnedFromLiveAPI = loadjson(getInfoSeptaLive);
% next line not needed - loadjson returns struct array, not cell array
%dataReturnedFromLiveAPI = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1};

%gets the size of the API in case there are no trains running
sizeOfDataNoTrains = size(dataReturnedFromLiveAPI, 1);
sizeOfData = size(dataReturnedFromLiveAPI, 2);

counter = 0;
stopAtEndOfData = sizeOfData;
closestTime = cell(1, stopAtEndOfData);
storeTheDifference = cell(1, stopAtEndOfData);
userEnteredMins = 12*60+30; % looking for a train around 12:30 pm

for ii = 1:sizeOfData
    scanForClosestTime = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI(ii).orig_departure_time;

    trainTimeGivenH = sscanf(scanForClosestTime, '%i');
    % since we'll be considering AM/PM, have to set 12 = 0:
    if (trainTimeGivenH == 12), trainTimeGivenH = 0; end
    findColonTrain = strfind(scanForClosestTime, ':');
    % change next line to get minutes plus AM/PM:
    trainTimeGivenMStr = scanForClosestTime(findColonTrain+(1:4));
    % look at just minutes:
    trainTimeGivenM = int32(str2num(trainTimeGivenMStr(1:2)));
    % adjust for AM/PM:
    if(trainTimeGivenMStr(3:4)=='PM'), trainTimeGivenH = trainTimeGivenH+12; end;
    % compute time in minutes:
    trainDepartTimeM = (trainTimeGivenH * 60) + (trainTimeGivenM);

    differenceBetweenTimes = trainDepartTimeM - userEnteredMins;
    if trainDepartTimeM < userEnteredMins
        differenceBetweenTimes = userEnteredMins - trainDepartTimeM;
    end
    % added a couple of lines to see what is happening:
    fprintf(1, 'train %d: depart %s - in minutes this is %d vs user entered %d\n', ...
        ii, scanForClosestTime, trainDepartTimeM, userEnteredMins);

    goodTimeFrame = 60;

    if(differenceBetweenTimes < 600)
        if (counter < 10)
            counter = counter + 1;
            closestTime{counter} = scanForClosestTime;
            storeTheDifference{counter} = differenceBetweenTimes;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: That worked better, but only the first two closest times showed up and the rest of the 3 were just [] brackets...any ideas why?

Comment: Could it be that differenceBetweenTimes is >60 for the others?

Comment: Your biggest problem was not handling AM/PM at all. I have updated my answer with a working code example.